# How to disable new Chrome Profiles for separate google accounts feature and go back to single Chrome instance?

Tags: google-chrome, google-account

I recently made the mistake of clicking "try" on a chrome prompt to open separate google accounts in separate profiles and i deeply regret that mistake and want to switch back.  it used to just switch the main chrome window.

in the other profiles i cannot access the passwords or bookmarks and things like the inspectors network profiler don't even work, blocking any real dev work.

How do i revert this setting?   Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed that by deleting additional profile and re-login into "lost" account.

How to remove profile:

- click on the profile picture in the upper right corner
- at the bottom of pop-up you fill find profiles section, press gear icon
- find newly created profile and remove it via actions menu (dots icon on the profile badge)

Linux, Chrome 91.0.4472.114